# Refreshing tkinter window without interfere

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to show the price of the bitcoin, getting the data from pybithumb. How can I refresh the Label every time, and able to click other buttons or something.

```
 class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, window):
        Frame.__init__(self, window)

        self.window = window
        self.window.title('BITCOIN')

        font = tkinter.font.Font(family="Cambria", size=15)

        self.current_price = Label(window, text = 'Default', width = 10 , height =1, font = font, relief = 'solid')
        self.current_price.place(x = 5, y = 5)

        self.select = ttk.Combobox(window, values=pybithumb.get_tickers())
        self.select.current(0)
        self.select.place(x = 135, y = 10)

    def get_price(self):
        while True:
            count = np.uint64(count + 1)
            try:
                price = np.float_(pybithumb.get_current_price("BTC"))
                self.current_price.config(text =price)
                self.window.update()
            except:
                messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Pybithumb just banned you')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500+300+300')
    myframe = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should edit your question! It's not clear what you want.

Comment: You can use `after()` instead of the while loop inside `get_price()`.